# How do I fix Array.filter to work as expected?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter out some items from an array, but nothing is getting filtered. I checked in the debugger and verified that the callback function in the second filter does return `false` for some items, but they're still not getting filtered out . . . The callback in the first filter is also working as expected.

```
this.datArr.filter(section=>section[0]==="foo")[0].
                filter(row=>+row[6].split("__")[1] !== activeItemToDelete)
```

Note the `[0]` after the first filter is to flatten the result.

For some entries, row[6] will contain `Email__1`, so the `split` call will produce a value of `1`, and `activeItemToDelete` also has a value of `1`, so rows containing `Email__1` should produce a false in the callback (I verified they are indeed producing a `false` value for `Email__1`), but those items are still not getting filtered out. I think it's OK to chain the two filters, but am I missing something?

Comment: `+row[6].split("__")[1] !== activeItemToDelete` why the `+`?

Comment: Can you also give sample input? It's hard to see what might be going wrong from logic that operates on data with certain shape when we don't know the shape of the data.

Comment: Also, are you using the *result* of `.filter`? The method returns a new array, doesn't filter in-place.

Comment: oneArray[0] doesn't flatten the result but return the first item of the array

Comment: Without seeing what does `dataArr` look like there is nothing to solve.

Comment: Please provide sample input and the desired output in certain conditions

Comment: @VLAZ - Sorry for my late reply. The "+" turns a `string` into a `number`

Answer (score 0):

the section that you pass to your function is a placeholder for your array. it represents the element of your array.

```
section[0] decleration is wrong.

let arr = [1,2];
//arr[0] will give you 1;

//but in your case your are trying to access arr[0][0]

[1,2].filter( section => {
    //here first value for section will be 1 
    // do whatever you need in here by using the keyword section not section[0]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Chalk this up to severe sleep deprivation . . . It turns out the `filter` was working as expected, but I think there is still (at least for me) a very important learning experience here and I hope my missteps will help others . . .

What I ended up doing is tantamount to the following:

```
>> foo=[1,2,3]
//foo.length = 3
>> foo["blah"] = 4
//foo:
//0: 1
//1: 2
//2: 3
//blah: 4
>> foo.length
// 3
// [Note: foo.length is still 3! I would have thought it now should be 4 after adding "blah"].
```

So in my original post, I thought I was replacing `this.datArr[2]` with the result of the filter, but in reality, I was effectively replacing `this.datArr["blah"]` with the result of the filter. As a result `this.datArr[2]` remained unchanged (which caused me to mistakenly believe the filter wasn't working) AND `this.datArr.length` remained unchanged, so at first I had no idea that I was assigning the `filter` results to the wrong (new) entry in `this.datArr`.